# How do I set the default user?

Tags: settings, 7.0-nougat, multi-user, motorola-moto-g5, setup-wizard

My device (Moto G5 Plus/Android 7.0) has two users: `Foo` and `Bar`.

`Foo` is the default one, created when I've setup my phone.

How do I set `Bar` as the default one and change `Foo` to be the secondary one?